# Laravel how to protect each step of order

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to protect each step of order from direct access to URL.

Example:

1. step of order has URL xxxx.com/step1
2. step of order has URL xxxx.com/step2 - if I try to do direct access to xxxx.com/step2 then redirect to xxxx.com/step1
3. step of order has URL xxxx.com/step3 - if I try to do direct access to xxxx.com/step3 then redirect to xxxx.com/step1

etc....

Do you advise me any good solution of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sessions for this. When step1 is completed you set in session that step2 is allowed, when step2 is completed you set in session that step3 is allowed, so you know what step is completed by user and you know whether you should allow him to access this url or not.